# Binding one listview to multiple xaml

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app

How to show one listview to multiple xaml?
on mainpage.xaml, i just want to show binding "Kata". another xaml i want to show binding "Kata" and "Description".

this mainpage.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="520" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Background="#33FFFFFF">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Kata}" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped_1" FontSize="26.667" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

this another xaml.

```
 <ListView x:Name="dictionary_list" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="620" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" Margin="10,10,0,0" Background="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Kata}" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="White" />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UserControl and one DependencyProperty whether to show or not description field
**ListViewUserContrl.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Listview.ListViewUserContrl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Listview"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    x:Name="ListViewUserControl">

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="dictionary_list" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="620" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" Margin="10,10,0,0" Background="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Kata}" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ListViewUserControl,Path=DescriptionVisibility}" Foreground="White" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ListViewUserContrl.xaml.cs**

```
 public sealed partial class ListViewUserContrl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionVisibilityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DescriptionVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(ListViewUserContrl),
                new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));
        public Visibility DescriptionVisibility
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(DescriptionVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DescriptionVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }
        public ListViewUserContrl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Add this to your page like this

```
<local:ListViewUserContrl DescriptionVisibility="Visible"/>
```